# OutOfMemoryException with Symfony4 + Doctrine2 Many-To-Many Bidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, out-of-memory

I have two entities, **MapParking** and **MapParkingType**. A MapParking (a parking lot) entity can have many types, and a MapParkingType (lot type) belong to many parking lots.

The problem I am having is that, when I get to about 50 entries deep in my join table, Symfony chokes whenever I try to load any view that uses MapParkingType entities in any way.

The error is:

> (1/1) OutOfMemoryException
>
> Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 23072768 bytes)

Here is my relevant MapParking entity class code:

```
class MapParking extends MapItem
{
...

/**
 * Many Parking lots have Many types.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Map\MapParkingType", inversedBy="parkingLots")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mapparking_types",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mapparking_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("parkingTypes")
 */
private $parkingTypes;

public function __construct() {
    $this->parkingTypes = new ArrayCollection();
}
...

public function getParkingTypes()
{
    return $this->parkingTypes;
}

public function addParkingType(MapParkingType $parkingType)
{
    if ($this->parkingTypes->contains($parkingType)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->parkingTypes->add($parkingType);
    $parkingType->addParkingLot($this);
}

public function removeParkingType(MapParkingType $parkingType)
{
    if (!$this->parkingTypes->contains($parkingType)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->parkingTypes->removeElement($parkingType);
    $parkingType->removeParkingLot($this);
}
}
```

And the relevant MapParkingType entity class code:

```
class MapParkingType
{
  ...

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MapParking", mappedBy="parkingTypes")
   */
  private $parkingLots;

  ...

  public function addParkingLot(MapParking $parkingLot)
  {
      if ($this->parkingLots->contains($parkingLot)) {
          return;
      }
      $this->parkingLots->add($parkingLot);
      $parkingLot->addParkingType($this);
  }

  public function removeParkingLot(MapParking $parkingLot)
  {
      if (!$this->parkingLots->contains($parkingLot)) {
          return;
      }
      $this->parkingLots->removeElement($parkingLot);
      $parkingLot->removeParkingType($this);
  }

}
```

**Interestingly enough**, if I get rid of the bi-directional nature of this relationship - that is, remove the inverse side's $parkingLots field, the problem goes away. However, I need this to be a bi-directional relationship.

For good measure, here is how MapParkingType entities are fetched via an API method:

```
public function getMapparkingtypesAction()
{
 $parkingTypes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MapParkingType::class)->findAll();

 $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
 $serialized = $serializer->serialize($parkingTypes, 'json');
 $response = new Response($serialized, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));

 return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a recursive call

The method `addParkingType` calls `addParkingLot` and viceversa that's why you are out of memory.

Comment: Actually, the if statements prevent the functions from being called over and over again. Because once a lot type / lot has been added, and vice versa, the return statement will be triggered and the function will exit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually didn't have anything to do with the type of relationship, but rather with the **serializer**. I had to exclude the MapParkingType's $parkingLots field from serialization.

```
// MapParkingType

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MapParking", mappedBy="parkingTypes")
 * @Serializer\Exclude
 */
private $parkingLots;
```

Something about serializing both sides of the relationship (using jms serializer bundle) sucks up all the system's memory.